# Memory issue when trying to initiate zero tensor with pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow, pytorch, memory

I am facing a memory issue while trying to initialize a torch.zeros -
`torch.zeros((2000,2000,3200), device=device)`

Getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 47.69 GiB (GPU 0; 8.00 GiB total capacity; 1.50 KiB already allocated; 6.16 GiB free; 2.00 MiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

My question is: why does a zero tensor need that big memory? Or am I doing any mistake?

P.S. I was checking with `getsizeof` in another system - the size of this tensor is showing as 72bytes only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the tensor takes up so much memory is because by default the tensor will store the values with the type `torch.float32`. This data type will use 4kb for each value in the tensor (check using `.element_size()`), which will give a total of ~48GB after multiplying with the number of zero values in your tensor (4 * 2000 * 2000 * 3200 = 47.68GB). What you could try to do is change the datatype from `torch.float32` to something like `torch.int8`, which only uses 1kb for each value, reducing the memory needed by 75% to 12GB. But given that you only seem to have 8GB available this will also not solve your problem. The only solution therefore would simply be to use a tensor will fewer values.

Comment: Thanks, I will see if I can reduce the size and will change the float to int.